# Java: java.lang.NullPointerException at booleanValue()

Tags: java

I have function foo() that returns true/false/null.

I have this piece of code:

```
Boolean flag = foo();
if (flag != null){
.....
}
```

When inspecting the `if` statement, I get the following exception: `java.lang.NullPointerException at booleanValue()`

Seems that it tries to evaluate its primitive value and compare it . However, this is what I do NOT want it to do. I want to check whether it is initialized...

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: The code you've shown should be fine - I suspect your problem lies elsewhere. Please show a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem. Alternatively, it may be to do with how you're performing the "inspection". Does the code *run* as you expect it to? Is this just a debugger issue? If so, how are you debugging and in which debugger?

Comment: Are you sure about that?  Please post the actual code (with line numbers!) and the actual exception stacktrace.

Comment: Definitely not using != false? How are you inspecting the statement? Your debugger might be converting it to a bool when you inspect.

Comment: In line with graphain's comment and because the name `booleanValue()` doesn't appear in your code, could it relate to this debugger method: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/PrimitiveValue.html#booleanValue%28%29

Answer (score 3):

```
    Boolean flag = null;
    if (flag != null){
        System.out.println("BLuh");
    }
```

This code runs fine - so the problem is defenetly elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you guys,

Ther simple code

Boolean flag = null;

if ( flag!=null)
...
else
...

Works for me too. It  is quite strange but I have figured out a workaroung. When I'll have time I'll get back to it and post and solution here.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The error indicates that something like this happens:

```
Boolean iAmNothing = null;
boolean crash = iAmNothing.booleanValue(); // throws NPE
```

or with outboxing (Java 1.5+):

```
Boolean iAmNothing = null;
boolean crash = iAmNothing;                // throws NPE
```

The code snippet shows none of these problems, so the NPE either occurs elsewhere inside the block behind the if statement or maybe you're not using the SUN jdk but a different one with different behaviour !?